# Future still returns null Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous

I have this function that calls a `Future<bool>` function :

```
bool checkId(String id, context) {
  bool ret;
  checkMissingId(id, context).then((value) => ret = value);
  return ret;
```

That calls :

```
Future<bool> checkMissingId(String id, context) async {
  String str = id.toLowerCase();
  String letter = str[0];
  if (checkStr(id, letter, str) == false)
    return false; //checks some rules on strings
  else {
    try {
      var data = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("ids/tabs/" + letter)
          .doc(str)
          .get();
      if (data.exists) {
        return false;
      } else
        return true;
    } catch (e) {
      await showErrDialog(context, e.code);
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

`ret` returns `null`, not a bool value.

Edit : checkId must be of type `bool`, not `Future<bool>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it is `null` when the `checkId` function returns. You should await the operation, like this:

```
Future<bool> checkId(String id, context) async {
  bool ret = await checkMissingId(id, context);
  return ret;
}
```

Comment: I want checkId to doesn't be of type Future<bool> but only bool.

Comment: You could use [`waitFor`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.3.1/dart-cli/waitFor.html), but it is experimental and not recommended to use, at all. There is really no reason to not use async, anyway.

Comment: Take a look at this please : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66297035/call-async-function-inside-textformfield-validator-flutter

Answer (score 0):

You need to pause the execution of the program for the `checkMissingId` method to complete before return the `ret` variable. You do this by using the `await` keyword and marking the function as `async`.

You should change the code to:

```
Future<bool> checkId(String id, context) async {
  bool ret = await checkMissingId(id, context);
  return ret;
}
```

Comment: I want checkId to be bool, not Future<bool>.

Comment: You're making an async call inside `checkId`. The return type has to be a `Future`. Is there any special reason you want it to be a bool return type?

Comment: Yes, I will do a new post to be more clear

Comment: Take a look at this please : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66297035/call-async-function-inside-textformfield-validator-flutter