# Call async function inside TextFormField validator Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous

In this code :

```
TextFormField(
        .
        .
        .
        validator: (value) => doFancy();
      ),
```

Where doFancy() is declared as :

```
Future<something> doFancy() async{...
```

How can I call `doFancy()` inside the `validator` of a `TextFormField` since it's a `Future` function and I can't declare the `validator` as `async`?

EDIT :
This is the best that I reached but I still have the same issue `The argument type 'Future<String> Function(String)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String Function(String)'`.

```
validator: (value) async {
          return (await checkMissingId(value, context) == false)
              ?  "Username already taken"
              :  null;
        },
```

Comment: But the textfield expects a <String> function, there is no reason for you to pass a future to it, if inside your validator you are executing asynchronous code, you must create a function of type string and add the async parameter and then work your methods asynchronous. If possible, add an example of this validator that uses asynchronous code.

Comment: Check my answer posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75685423/11217849). Maybe it will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the async keyword:

```dart
TextFormField(
        .
        .
        .
        validator: (value) async => doFancy();
      ),
```

Comment: It says : The argument type 'Future<String> Function(String)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String Function(String)'.

Comment: code :

        validator: (value) async => (checkMissingId(value, context)==false) ? "Username already taken" : null ,

Comment: Add "await" before checkMissingId" doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

Solved moving out the async function and working with variables handled in setState .